# Need Help: Tracking google ad app install campaign

Tags: android, flutter

**Context**

We are running multiple app install campaign via google adwords. We need to understand completed funnel data(from app install to conversion).

**Problem**

When user see our ad in play store and install the app, we are not able to capture that referral parameters passed by google adwords in play console or app level.

I tried to make changes in code and able to capture UTM parameters from firebase dynamic link  but I am still not able to capture parameters passed by google ad campaign.

Is there any configuration we need to do in google adwords/play console/code to capture them?